# How can one set up Git source control with full mesh topology?

Tags: git, topology

I have a local network of several computers that each have a local Git repository of the same code, with different developers working on them.
I would like to find a way to synchronize the changes in each of the local repositories with all of the others, without having a centralized server.

(In case you're interested, this is because any computer can - and often does - suffer sudden a disk malfunction, usually causing all the data on it to be lost, and so I can't afford to have a single point of failure.)

I've seen several examples of workflow possibilities, but they all require the setup to have fixed remote systems.

What I'd like to know is:
How can I set up a set of repositories that can synchronize with the repositories in all the other computers in the network, as in a [full mesh topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully-connected_network)?

And how would I then add/remove computers to this repository network?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the repositories is easy enough.  Just set up a public repository on every developer's system.

To automatically sync to everyone, you'd probably have to write some sort of shell script to do pushes and pulls that's stored in the repo itself.  To add a computer, you just add a `git push new-computer` to the script.

However, a centralized server isn't a "single point of failure" with DVCS.  If it goes down, you just collaborate from someone else's repo until it comes back up.  You're adding a lot of complexity to avoid a relatively rare occurrence that's fairly easy to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a centralized server. If the disk on the centralized server fails, you will not lose all data. Every developer will already have the same complete copy of the repository that he would have if he had not been using a centralized server. To recover, your developers can just nominate a new centralized server and push to that.